# what is going wrong in my code while publishing web app using visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

an error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. could not find file 'd:\home\site\wwwroot\app_offline.htm'

getting this error while publishing code using visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

- WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE  lets you run a Web App by  pointing it to a zip file containing your files.
- Either delete  `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` OR Set the value to 0.
- After setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` ,delete the publish profile from Visual Studio and add it again (then publish again).
- Go to Azure Portal => You Web App =>Configurations -> Application settings, change the value of '**WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE**' from '1' to '0' or delete it.

Change from WebDeploy (which is default) to ZipDeploy in "Azure App Service Deploy" step.

[image]

Comment: my application version is 2 then what task version should i select in CD pipeline

Comment: Please refer [Task versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#task-versions)